# Making portion of textfield read-only jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have a portion of text in a jquery mobile textbox read-only?

If the following brackets are my textbox, I want to the word "happy" to be untouchable

```
[happy...................]
```

In other words, people should be able to delete all those period up until they reach the y. Possible, or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to try something like this:

**JS / jQuery code:**

```
// Your untouchable string
var my_string = "happy";

$(function () {

    // The following function makes sure that when the user is typing, //
    // the user won't touch the word "happy"
    $("#my_input").keyup(function () {
        var string = $(this).val();

        if(string.length >= my_string.length) {
            if(string.substring(0, my_string.length) != my_string) {
                // This part makes sure that the user won't modify the word "happy"
                $(this).val(my_string+string.substring(my_string.length+1, string.length));
            }
        } else {
            // This part makes sure that the user won't typed:
            //   - before the word "happy" (eg: "Zhappy")
            //   - inside the word "happy" (eg: "hapZpy")
            $(this).val(my_string);
        }
    });
});
```

**The HTML (example):**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">

            <!-- The value of your input is initially set to your untouchable string -->
            <input id="my_input" type="text" value="happy"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.